# Java heap size values do not get change

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have set java heap size using below command in a spring boot application.

```
java -Xms512m -Xmx1024m -jar test.jar
```

But when I examine the sizes again using below command I dont see the values change?

```
java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -version | grep -iE 'HeapSize|PermSize|ThreadStackSize'
```

Comment: These flags affect the invocation you made them in only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are  not *examining heap size again*. The second command starts a separate Java process and will therefore start with default heap size (since you have not provided `Xms/Xmx` to it). That second process exits as soon as it prints the version.

To check the heap size of an already running Java process you can do one of the following:

- connect to the running JVM using profiler, JMX,
- In the running program, invoke `Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory/maxMemory` or
- use the `jcmd` or `jstat`  tools (both are part of the `JDK`).